# WordPress 2.8 to 4.2.2

Tags: wordpress

Yes, this is ridiculous but I inherited this issue.  So we have wordpress 2.8 and need to upgrade it to 4.2.2.  We've tried using the export/import function built into WP but its not bringing everything in correctly.  We also tried grabbing the mysql and importing into a new table.  Is this even possible or is 2.8 to 4.2.2 so different that we are SOL?

Comment: offtopic, not a programming question. but if 4.2 can't import something so old, then upgrade to intermediate old versions, which presumably can. e.g. 2.8 -> 2.9 -> 3.0 -> 3.x -> 4.0 -> 4.2 or whatever.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't rebuild the site?

Answer (score 1):

Woah. A lot has changed between 2.x and 4.x, including the version of PHP used, and that's mainly why you can't just do a direct upgrade.

See here for information about which version of WP uses which version of PHP and MySQL: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template:Server_requirements

So your best bet is to ever so slowly upgrade through the intermediary versions, and simultaneously updating your PHP version as you go along.

Please remember to create a comprehensive backup of your server before you start.

Your other option is to copy the content-bearing MySQL tables, the content folder, and paste them into a brand new 4.x site and simply reconstruct from scratch. (This is what I would do because upgrading through the version can frankly be a messy process.)